# Counting the particular words from array in other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to count the number of times, when specific words of array B appeared in array A.

I tried the code below, but the output is 0. I do not understand, why it logs me the value that I assigned to the variable in the beginning of the function and does not run the 'for' cycle.

```
let A = ['really', 'basically', 'After', 'a','quick', 'popular', 'really', 'Red', 'began', 'very'];
let B = ['really', 'very'];

let number = () => {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i=0; i < A.lengths; i++) {
    if (B.includes(A[i])) {
      return count++;
    }
  }
   return console.log(count);
 }

number();
```

I expect the result should be 3.

Comment: You neither want to `return count++;` nor `return console.log(count);`. You want to `count++;`, `return count`, and `console.log(number());`.

Comment: in your loop, do you really have  `A.lengths` ? If so, remove the 's' so that it is:  `A.length`

Comment: As a sidenote, having `B` as a hashtable/object would drastically improve performance, for larger inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

- `length` as property for the size of the array
- go on with the loop and not return early
- mabye return the count, by returning the result of `console.log`, you get `undefined`.

A good idea,

- is to take the two arrays as parameter for the function,
- take a `const` declaration/initialization because this variable is a constant,
- is to use small starting letter for variables.

```js
const number = (a, b) => {
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (b.includes(a[i])) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
   };

let array1 = ['really', 'basically', 'After', 'a','quick', 'popular', 'really', 'Red', 'began', 'very'];
let array2 = ['really', 'very'];


console.log(number(array1, array2));
```

Comment: @AritraGhosh, maybe, but your solution creates a new array, which is superfluous, just for the count. and `filter` loops as well. and you might have a look to the performance about `for` and `filter`.

Comment: Sure.. have a look https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS.. short term gains are never better for small subsets of data

Answer (score 2):

One liner => `A.filter(item => B.includes(item)).length;`

Answer (score 0):

why do you this: `return count++;`?

`return` is meant to break out of the function with the value its given. When you write `return count++;`, it returns the count and only then increments it (actually it doesn't increment anything cuz you're out of the function scope already at this point).

The `return console.log(count)` also does nothing- apart from the code never getting there unless no words are found at B, this will return the return value from `console.log` which is undefined.

do this:

```
let number = () => {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i=0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (B.includes(A[i])) {
      count++;
    }
  }
   console.log(count);
   return count;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1- **length** -> not lengths

2- **includes** only checks if that value exists in that array so it returns true or false

3- **return** statement terminates the execution of a function

So as i understood you are counting occurrence of B elements in A

This is a way of doing it :

```js
let A = ['really', 'basically', 'After', 'a','quick', 'popular', 'really', 'Red', 'began', 'very'];
let B = ['really', 'very'];

let number = () => {
  let count = 0;
  for (let i=0; i < B.length; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j < A.length; j++){
      if (B[i] === A[j]) count++;
    }
    console.log(count);
    count = 0;
  }
   
 }

number();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use higher order functions like [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead loop.

```js
let A = ['really', 'basically', 'After', 'a','quick', 'popular', 'really', 'Red', 'began', 'very'];
let B = ['really', 'very'];

let total = B.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue){

    let founds = A.filter(function(value,index){
        return value == currentValue;
    }).length;

    return accumulator + founds;

},0);


console.log(total);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add another for statement to iterate through elements in B and then check if A at [i] is equal to B at [j]. Probably not as efficient as the other answers though.

```
 let A = ['really', 'basically', 'After', 'a', 'quick', 'popular', 'really', 'Red', 'began', 'very'];
 let B = ['really', 'very'];

    let number = () => {
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            for(let j=0; j < B.length; j++){
                if (A[i] == B[j]){
                    count++
                }
            }
        }
        return console.log(count);
    }

    number();
```

Comment: 1. he does not need another loop, he uses the `array.includes` method. 
2. you return the console.log as he did, rendering the whole function useless...

Comment: I assume smokedsalmon is returning console.log to be able to view what is being returned. That is the reason I kept the console.log. Also I included another loop to show another way of doing it. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: In other case i'd understand, but seeing how he used return in the middle of the function- im not sure he knows what it really means. This will indeed print the count, but the return value will be lost. you can put the console.log beforehand and return the count, and still seeing it in console.